# Interestingly, why $A$ is not only nonsymmetric, also dense

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

For equation $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=-(-\Delta)u$ with zero boundary condition  using finite element method. Applying the corresponding weak formulation and taking $v=\phi_{j},j=1,2,...,N$, We obtain the following equation.

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} \frac{du_{i}}{dt}\int _{\Omega} \phi_{i}\phi_{j}d\Omega=-\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}u_{i} \int _{\Omega} \nabla\phi_{i}.\nabla\phi_{j}d\Omega $.

introducing the mass matrix $\mathcal {M}_{i,j}=\int _{\Omega} \phi_{i}\phi_{j}d\Omega$and stiffness matrix $\mathcal{K}_{i,j}=\int _{\Omega} \nabla\phi_{i}.\nabla\phi_{j}d\Omega$.

Then we have 
$\frac{d\bf{u}}{dt}=-\mathcal{M}^{-1}\mathcal{K}\bf{u}$.

so far, we have derived the approximation matrix representation of the standard Laplacian for the finite element method is $A=\mathcal{M}^{-1}\mathcal{K}$.

So my question is  that why $A$ is not only nonsymmetric, also dense.
Although both $\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{K}$ are $\bf {SPD}$ and sparse

Comment: Because a product of symmetric matrices is seldom symmetric and the inverse of a sparse matrix is usually dense? What were you expecting? Look into matrix stencils.

Comment: could you give a brief proof about that discussion above? @LutzL

Comment: One does not prove a negative, one only needs to provide counter-examples. As I understand your question, you already have these counter-examples. As matrix identities are polynomial identities, they either are true everywhere or only on a subset of positive co-dimension, or in the sparse case, on the finite union of subsets of positive co-dimension. In terms of density, this means almost nowhere.